# p_threads: Condition Variable Locking

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

Let's say I had 4 threads, a producer and three consumers, a single mutex and a single condition variable, every consumer runs the same function that does the below:

```
mutexlock(mutex)
signal[i] = 1;
while(signal[i] == 1) {
condwait(cond, mutex)
}
mutexunlock(mutex)
```

And the producer does the below

```
if(signal == 1) 
{
set 0 - atomically using CAS
mutexlock(mutex)
condbroadcast(cond)
mutexunlock(mutex)
}
```

Let's say if more than one consumer were in that lock, wouldn't they fight for the cond variable? Should I create one for each thread or can p_thread condition variables be shared accross multiple threads without any race conditions?

Comment: You issued a broadcast. *Every* thread actively waiting on that condition signal will be bumped to the line waiting on the mutex. And fyi, this "code" make no sense if the `signal` in the first text is the `signal` in the second (one is an array, the other... not). And even if they are somehow supposed to be the same, the `if()` in the second should be under the protection of the mutex, as it contains the predicate state, which is the entire point of the mutex. Wrapping the actual condition notify or broadcast is pointless. The mutex is to protect the predicate; not the cvar.

Comment: The second code batch has indeed signal as an array too, I just forgot to put it, also the second signal is protected by a CAS condition - which I believe is less heavy than locking for every time I have to broadcast the condition...

Comment: *Real Code* : It's What's For Dinner.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `pthread_const_broadcast()` over `pthread_cond_signal()`?

Comment: @alk because multiple threads may be sleeping at the same time, and I'm not sure to make all of them up with cond_signal, if they wake up and their signal condition is still up, they just go back to sleep

Answer (score 0):

When you create a muti-thread program,they share the resource signal[i] and all the three thread will compete for the resources.When signal[i] == 0,the threads which didn't get the resource will be put into the queue of the condition variable.And when you send a broadcast,all the waiting threads in the condition variable will weak up and compete for the resouce.Here is a [tourial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) for muti-thread beginner in C.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic of `pthread_cond_wait` is to release acquired mutex and block on conditional variable. When signal arrives, block is released, then `pthread_cond_wait` acquires the lock on mutex.

So, in your case, when you use `pthread_cond_broadcast` all threads blocked on conditional will move past this point, but after that one of them will be granted lock on mutex. Which one? It depends on the order the scheduler wakes them up after being unblocked and the pthread implementation in case two or more threads try to acquire the lock at the some moment. It's safe to consider it's random.

If you replace `pthread_cond_broadcast` with `pthread_cond_signal`, the signal will be delivered to some threads. Yes, it is expected to be one, but sometimes more than one can be released from conditional variable. Still, the thread (or threads) to deliver signal to will be chosen by scheduler. And if more than one is waked up from cond waiting, they will fight for the mutex. As previously - you can consider the result as random.

Let's look into [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal):

> If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are unblocked.
>
> On a multi-processor, it may be impossible for an implementation of pthread_cond_signal() to avoid the unblocking of more than one thread blocked on a condition variable.

BTW, I am quite curious. There are several questions about conditional variables recently (are you guys all doing a project for your uni or what?) and in every question I have seen in last 24 hours I have seen a following pattern for signalling:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond); /* or signal */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

when waiting threads have:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
/* do something */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

What's the reason behind that?

Waiting threads wait on `cond`, `mutex` is released. So signalling thread acquires lock on `mutex`, signals other threads. In this very moment they - still being inside the `pthread_cond_wait` progress past the `cond` blockade, then they try to acquire the lock on `mutex`. And, of course, they cannot, because the lock is hold by signalling thread. Then, signalling thread releases `mutex` and waiting threads can finally process by acquiring - one by one - the `mutex`.

For signalling writer and waiting consumers this pattern should be as below.

For writer:

```
while(loop_condition) {
    prepare_data() /* it could be a long process */
    lock(&mutex);
    add_data_to_queue(); /* fast, inside critical section */
    unlock(&mutex);
    signal(&cond); /* or broadcast */
}
```

For consumers:

```
while(consumer_loop_condition) {
    lock(&mutex);
    while(!data_ready_to_process()) {
        wait(&cond,&mutex);
    }
    fetch_data(); /* fast, still inside critical section */
    unlock(&mutex);
    if(got_data) {
        process_data(); /* could be a long process */
    }
}
```

Please see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44417229/2989411) for some more explanation on cond/mutexes and some example code to play with.